# Functions with pre millenium dates in q

Tags: kdb

I've built a function in q such that I can see how many Sunday's fall on the 1st of the month between two dates

```
\W 1 f3:{[sd;ed] count distinct `week$(sd + til 1 + ed - sd) where (`dd$distinct `week$sd + til 1 + ed - sd)=01}
```

How can I edit with to work with pre 2000 dates? Can I put a modulus around the negative dates? Or will that redender my function incorrect?

Comment: The function above can be run with pre 2000 dates, what is the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: I have not looked into the function in detail but it is not giving correct answer for pre 2000 dates

Comment: Also this will not work correctly for some of the cases post 2000 dates . Need some fixes to handle those. For ex: f3[2018.06.01;2018.07.02] returns 0 where it should return 1.

Comment: @Rahul the above function works fine for the example date you've given. Have you set \W 1 in your q session?

Comment: @Scott Thanks. I missed that part. Working fine after setting week offset.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
    q) f:{sum 1=mod[`date$a[1] + til 1+(-). a:(0;1<`dd$x)+`month$(y;x);7]}
    q) f[2018.01.01;2018.12.31]  / 2
    q) f[1998.01.02;1999.12.31]  / 4
```